# Jquery passing data via .load

Tags: php, jquery, forms, load

I'm not sure why i can' t get my output to surface. It shouldn't be too hard but has been stuck for several hours. All i

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chat_submit').click(function(){
        var data="{'chat_content:'+$('#chat_content').val()+'chat_from_who:'+$('#chat_from_who').val()+'chat_to_who:'+$('#chat_from_who').val()+'order_no:'+$('#order_no').val()}";
        $('#order_chatbox').load('/seller/helpers/order_chat.php',data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pass the whole url it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chat_submit').click(function(event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            chat_content: $('#chat_content').val(),
            chat_from_who: $('#chat_from_who').val(),
            chat_to_who: $('#chat_from_who').val(),
            order_no: $('#order_no').val()
        };
        $('#order_chatbox').load('/seller/helpers/order_chat.php', data);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the data as a long string.. not as an object.

Change it to

```
var data= {'chat_content': $('#chat_content').val(),
    'chat_from_who': $('#chat_from_who').val(),
    'chat_to_who': $('#chat_from_who').val(),
    'order_no': $('#order_no').val()};
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know why i didn' spot the error. I guess i was too tired.